# How to set title only for a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

In my activity, I have 5 different fragments. I want to change the title for only one `Fragment` other Fragment's title will be same. I've used following code, but it changes title for all Fragments. How can I change title for only a specific `Fragment`?

```java
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Create Post")
```

Comment: At where have you written above line? In Specific fragment?

Comment: @Piyush yes. in `onCreate()` method of a specific fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating class named StatefulFragment (extends Fragment) and creating String fragmentTitle inside this class which contains your title (like this)

```
public class StatefulFragment extends Fragment {
    public String fragmentTitle = "";
}
```

Use this class for initialize all your fragments (extend them from StatefulFragment).

Then I recommend to hide ActionBar from your activity and add Toolbar to your all fragment's views (and initialize it in fragment's class). And then just set fragment's title which we added to fragment's toolbar:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Toolbar myToolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
        myToolbar.setTitle(fragmentTitle);
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Hope it helps!